# Would storing data in a wide format achieve better performance in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to get my head around Snowflake's capabilities around wide-tables.

I have a table of the form:

| userId | metricName | value | asOfDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'meanSessionTime' | 30 | 2022-01-04 |
| 1 | 'meanSessionSpend' | 20 | 2022-01-04 |
| 2 | 'meanSessionTime' | 34 | 2022-01-05 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

However, for my analysis I usually pull big subsets of this table into Python and pivot out the metric names

| userId | asOfDate | meanSessionTime | meanSessionSpend | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | 30 | 20 | ... |
| 2 | 2022-01-05 | 43 | 12 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I am thinking of generating this Pivot in Snowflake (via DBT, the SQL itself is not hard), but I'm not sure if this is good/bad.

Any good reasons to keep the data in the long format? Any good reasons to go wide?

Note that I don't plan to always `SELECT *`  from the wide table, so it may be a good usecase for the columnar storage.

### Note:

These are big tables (billions or records, hundreds of metrics), so I am looking for a sense-check before a burn a few hundred $ in credits doing an experiment.

Comment: Can you provide any more details on the total number of metrics ?

Comment: Also is it likely that you will have to deal with new metrics being added to the data-model over time?   Are the metrics dense, or sparse with a lot of NULL/default values, and would you store the NULL/default value rows, or impute them at query time?  What's the typical query column count payload you are expecting, given you've said that you're not always selecting every column in a query.  How many users ?  Do all the metrics for a given user change at the same time , or only small subset.

Comment: @Fieldy, we have ~600 metrics. They are dense, and new features will be added ~annually. The historical data is not updated, so this could be treated as an append only dataset. Probably will be selecting 20-100 columns at any one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the additional details provided in the comments and apologies for delayed response. A few thoughts.

I've used both Wide and Tall tables to represent feature/metric stores in Snowflake. You can also potentially use semi-structured column(s) to store the Wide representation.  Or in the Tall format if your metrics can be of different data-types (e.g. numeric & character), to store the metric value in a single VARIANT column.

With ~600 metrics (columns), you are still within the limits of Snowflakes row width, but the wider the table gets, generally the less useable/manageable it becomes when writing queries against it, or just retrieving the results for further analysis.

The wide format will typically result in a smaller storage footprint than the tall format, due to the repetition of the key (e.g. user-id, asOfDate) and metricName, plus any additional columns you might need in the tall form. I've seen 3-5x greater storage in the Tall format in some implementations so you should see some storage savings if you move to the Wide model.

In the Tall table this can be minimised through [clustering](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html) the table so the same key and/or metric column values are gathered into the same micro-partitions, which then favours better compression and access.  Also, as referenced in my comments/questions, if some metrics are sparse, or have a dominant default value distribution, or change value at significantly different rates, moving to a sparse-tall form can enable  more much efficient storage and processing.  In the wide form, if only one metric value changes out of 600, on a given day, you still need to write a new record with all 599 unchanged values. Whereas in the tall form you could write a single record for the metric with the changed value.

In the wide format, Snowflakes columnar storage/access should effectively eliminate physical scanning of columns not included within the queries so they should be at least as efficient as the tall format, and columnar compression techniques can effectively minimise the physical storage.

Assuming your data is not being inserted into the tall table in optimal sequence for your analysis patterns the table will need to be [clustered](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html) to get the best performance using CLUSTER BY.  For example if you are always filtering on a subset of user-ids, it should take precedence in your CLUSTER BY, but if you are mainly going after a subset of columns, for all, or a subset of all, user-ids then the metricName should take precedence.  Clustering has an additional service cost which may become a factor in using the tall format.

In the tall format, having a well defined standard for metric names enables a programmatic approach to column selection. e.g. [column names as contracts](https://emilyriederer.netlify.app/post/column-name-contracts/)  This makes working with groups of columns as a unit very effective using the WHERE clause to 'select' the column groups (e.g. with LIKE), and apply operations on them efficiently.  IMO this enables much more concise & maintainable SQL to be written, without necessarily needing to use a templating tool like Jinja or DBT.

Similar flexibility can be achieved in the wide format, by grouping and storing the metric name/value pairs within OBJECT columns, rather than as individual columns. They can be gathered (Pivoted) to an Object with [OBJECT_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_agg.html). Snowflakes semi-structured functionality can then be used on the object.  Snowflake implicitly columnarises semi-structured columns, up to a point/limit, but with 600+ columns, some of your data will not benefit from this which may impact performance. If you know which columns are the most commonly used for filtering or returned in queries you could use a hybrid of the two approaches

I've also used Snowflake UDFs to effectively perform commonly required filter, project or transform operations over the OBJECT columns using Javascript, but noting that you're using Python, the new Python UDF functionality may be a better option for you.  When you retrieve the data to Python for further analysis you can easily convert the OBJECT to a DICT in Python for further iteration.  You could also take a look at [Snowpark for Python](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/index.html), which should enable you to push further analysis and processing from Python into Snowflake.

Comment: Awesome; very informative.

Answer (score 0):

You could of course not choose between the two options, but go with both. If CPU dominates storage in your cloud costs, then you might get the best bang for your buck by maintaining the data in both forms, and picking the best target for any given query.

You can even consider creating views that present the one from as the other one, if query convenience outweighs other concerns.

Another option is to split your measures out by volatility. Store the slow moving ones with a date range key in a narrow (6NF) table and the fast ones with snapshot dates in a wide (3NF) table. Again a view can help present an simpler user access point (although I guess the Snowflake optimizer won't be do join pruning over range predicates, so YMMV on the view idea).

Non-1NF gives you more options too on DBMSes like Snowflake that have native support for "semi-structured" `ARRAY`, `OBJECT`, and `VARIANT` column values.

BTW do update us if you do any experiments and get comparison numbers out. Would make a good blog post!